# Git error: unable to create temprary file & error building trees with no further info?

Tags: windows, git, commit

I'm trying to commit new changes to my repo, but it fails with the following errors:

```
error: unable to create temporary file: Invalid argument
error: unable to create temporary file: Invalid argument
error: Error building trees
```

When others faced similar issues, the error would point to a specific file/object which was causing the issue, however here there is no additional info to go on.

(Windows 10, tried through Terminal and cmd)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the issue - the project folder was being synced with OneDrive, which corrupted (*The tag present in the reparse point buffer is invalid*) one of the files in the `objects` folder inside `.git`. Figuring out where the issue lies could be done either visually (for me it was the only folder with blue OneDrive sync arrows instead of the green tick and the folder couldn't be opened). Another way is to clone the problematic branch into a new folder, make a small change (I created a `test.txt` with "test" written inside), push it to git, then go back to the problematic project folder and try to pull new changes from git. This operation failed and pointed to the corrupted object.

To solve this I looked into how to deal with files which OneDrive corrupted, and the most common suggestion was to run [`chkdsk c: /r /f`](https://www.itexperience.net/fix-onedrive-the-tag-present-in-the-reparse-point-buffer-is-invalid/) in Command Prompt (as admin), which starts when the computer is rebooted. Beware it can take several hours to complete.

Answer (score 4):

General Windows Solution (tested on Windows 10 and 11):
I'm getting the error because it appears that windows put the folder in read only mode

Deselect read only, then click apply and ok

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Git really ought to print the path here, yes.  The error seems to come from [object-file.c:write_loose_object()](https://github.com/git/git/blob/af4e5f569bc89f356eb34a9373d7f82aca6faa8a/object-file.c#L1906-L1928), which is going to be creating a temporary file within `.git/objects` in the normal case.

The `EINVAL` error case *should* **never** occur, as the object path itself is necessarily valid (otherwise how did it come into existence?) and the generated temporary file name uses entirely "safe" characters.  So the missing `filename.buf` in the error message should never comes out in the first place.  In your case, the error does come out, and the missing `%s` for `filename.buf` means we can't see what path it is that your OS is objecting to.

You could build a debug or private version of Git (that adds the missing path) to find out, or use whatever system-call tracing facilities you have to observe the failing system call some other way.  Find out why the OS is rejecting the attempt to create the loose object temporary file, and correct whatever the underlying problem may be.  Meanwhile you might want to report this to the Git mailing list.